# Using svg icon as background of a div container

Tags: css, svg

I have a svg icon which you can find [here](http://mobileglas.tryit.ch/fileadmin/media/images/Mobile_kreuz.svg) (it's white) and I would like to use it as the background of a div. How can I do this?

I have tried it like this but it is showing nothing:

```
.show_nav {
    background-image: url('http://mobileglas.tryit.ch/fileadmin/media/images/Mobile_kreuz.svg');
    height: 5px; 
    width:30px;
}
```

Comment: It's there but it's not resizing because you have fixed size values built in. You'll probably have to remove those if you want it to scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your background is simply not large enough to see the cross on. If you want the cross to scale change the SVG width and height values to 100% rather than px values.

```css
.show_nav {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url('http://mobileglas.tryit.ch/fileadmin/media/images/Mobile_kreuz.svg');
    height: 320px; 
    width:530px;
}
```

```html
<div class="show_nav"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your svg is too big and has a lot of white space. You can try two things:

1. You can try changing the viewbox to (456 256 960 563) OR
2. simple resize this svg in Adobe Illustrator and also remove the
   extra space of the drawing board.